# How to set a background color with respect to near in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, background-color

I have got a task to set background color for each div with slightly different color of near.
The div is generating dynamically.So how can i set the background color with this div?

For eg: I have a starting color of **`#fdecbb`**

I need a related color of the above. May be I need 10 or less.

```
var x =parseInt($('#colorNo').val());
var y = $('#colorCode').val();
for(var i =1;i<x;i++)
{
    $('#hai').append($('<div class="colorcode">'+i+'</div>')); 
}
```

The **CSS**

```
.colorcode
{
    background-color:#86173e;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

The HTML

```
<div id="hai"><input type="text" value="5" id="colorNo"/><input type="text" value="#fdecbb" id="colorCode"/></div>
```

Demo :[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9nYvQ/1/)

Comment: What about adding or subtracting let's say 10 from the given color?

Comment: @prady00 must to add ...

Comment: @Tamizh-wait i will update it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9nYvQ/1/

Answer (score 1):

Find the closest / nearest HEX color of a small set of colours

The **JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function getSimilarColors (color) {

        var base_colors=["660000","990000","cc0000","cc3333","ea4c88","993399","663399","333399","0066cc","0099cc","66cccc","77cc33","669900","336600","666600","999900","cccc33","ffff00","ffcc33","ff9900","ff6600","cc6633","996633","663300","000000","999999","cccccc","ffffff"];

        //Convert to RGB, then R, G, B
        var color_rgb = hex2rgb(color);
        var color_r = color_rgb.split(',')[0];
        var color_g = color_rgb.split(',')[1];
        var color_b = color_rgb.split(',')[2];

        //Create an emtyp array for the difference betwwen the colors
        var differenceArray=[];

        //Function to find the smallest value in an array
        Array.min = function( array ){
               return Math.min.apply( Math, array );
        };


        //Convert the HEX color in the array to RGB colors, split them up to R-G-B, then find out the difference between the "color" and the colors in the array
        $.each(base_colors, function(index, value) { 
            var base_color_rgb = hex2rgb(value);
            var base_colors_r = base_color_rgb.split(',')[0];
            var base_colors_g = base_color_rgb.split(',')[1];
            var base_colors_b = base_color_rgb.split(',')[2];

            //Add the difference to the differenceArray
            differenceArray.push(Math.sqrt((color_r-base_colors_r)*(color_r-base_colors_r)+(color_g-base_colors_g)*(color_g-base_colors_g)+(color_b-base_colors_b)*(color_b-base_colors_b)));
        });

        //Get the lowest number from the differenceArray
        var lowest = Array.min(differenceArray);

        //Get the index for that lowest number
        var index = differenceArray.indexOf(lowest);

        //Function to convert HEX to RGB
        function hex2rgb( colour ) {
            var r,g,b;
            if ( colour.charAt(0) == '#' ) {
                colour = colour.substr(1);
            }

            r = colour.charAt(0) + colour.charAt(1);
            g = colour.charAt(2) + colour.charAt(3);
            b = colour.charAt(4) + colour.charAt(5);

            r = parseInt( r,16 );
            g = parseInt( g,16 );
            b = parseInt( b ,16);
            return r+','+g+','+b;
        }

        //Return the HEX code
        return base_colors[index];
    }

    //Just for the demo
    $('button').click(function(){        
        $('.base_color').css('backgroundColor',$('input').val());
        $('.nearest_color').css('backgroundColor','#'+getSimilarColors($('input').val()));
        return false;
    });
});
```

The **HTML**

Get the closest color

```
<p>Base color:</p>
<div class="base_color"></div>

<p>Closest color:</p>
<div class="nearest_color"></div>
```

The **CSS**

```
div {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin:0 0 0 20px;
}

p {
    margin:20px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kJdX3/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this:

- From a rgb code, I randomly choose R,G or B value, and I randomly add or substract a value (here defined in step variable, so as you can change it the way you want).

  ```
  $(function(){
      var step = 10;
      $('#new').on('click',function(){
          $lastDiv = $('#wrapper > div:last');
          nearColor = $lastDiv.css('backgroundColor');
          nearColor = nearColor.replace('rgb(','').replace(')','').split(', ');
          rgb = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3));
          plusminus = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2)) + 1;
          colorToChange = nearColor[rgb];
          if(1 === plusminus){
              colorToChange = (255 == colorToChange) ? 255-step :         Math.min(parseInt(colorToChange)+step,255);

          }
          else {
              colorToChange = (0 == colorToChange) ? step     :Math.max(parseInt(colorToChange)-    step,0);
          }

          nearColor[rgb] = colorToChange;
          $lastDiv.after('<div style="background:rgb('+nearColor.join()+')" ></div>');
      });

  });
  ```

You can check the fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/39Wjy/)